How do I record the link of a web page and store it in a variable?
Basically in my project I open a web page using webbrowser and then type something into the search bar with pyautogui, which opens a new page. I need a function that finds the link of the new page and stores it as a variable so I can have a dynamic requests.get() function. I hope my explanation makes sense.
I don't know how to retrieve it and save it as a variable, I can retrieve it as text or something, but then it won't save as a variable to the same code that is running

I would recommend using a python module known as selenium. It allow for the browsing of the web pages html in real time and allow for javascript to work. Plus with selenium you shouldn't have to use the request module and can just feed the data you get from it into beautiful soup. You can install selenium by using the pip install selenium command. What site are you trying to build this for btw?
If you need more assistance I would be happy to link you examples and one of my past projects that is similar to this one!
Use the following link to look at an example
How to use Selenium with Python?
Instead of using find_element_by_xpath() use find_element_by_id() to access page attributes. Then use mydriver.getCurrentUrl().

Thanks, I know about selenium, but I haven't really used it before, so some examples would be helpful. As for the site I'm trying to build, I can't exactly say lol. But its for an internship project.

Use marionette's
.get_url() method to query your browser for its current URL,
similar to selenium's .getCurrentUrl().

Does marionette work with chrome? I can't seem to get it to work

The OP use the term "webbrowser", suggesting that you had flexibility to choose the one you found most suitable. Mozilla's marionette was designed to address firefox issues, rather than chrome ones. Selenium is browser agnostic; I mentioned its .getCurrentUrl() method in case it was needed for your particular use case.

You can use libraries like selenium for browser automation and requests for HTTP requests.
